# Border radius and box shadow have no effect in Android 2.3.6

Tags: android, cordova, css

I ran my Phonegap app in three devices, Android 2.3.6, Android 3 and iOS7 . The problem is that on the Android 2.3.6 I see that the switch button using the jQuery switchery plugin is square instead of being rounded, as it renders in the other phones.

[image]

Things I've done that didn't work out:

- Use cross browser border radius (e.g. -web-kit, -moz, etc.)
- Added !important

The code of the rounded switch from switchery jquery plugin:

```
.switchery>small {
 background: #fff;
 border-radius: 100%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 100%; 
 border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 20px; 
box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 30px;
```

}

I can't use a developer tools to debug the css on the device.

Comment: Did you try `-webkit-box-shadow`? It works on Android browser 2.1+, Also in order to create a circle, you should use `border-radius: 50%;`

Comment: ok, box-shadow works now, but can't get the circle, when used border-radius 50% I get empty space

Comment: What about `border-radius: 15px;`? (Android 2.1 and iOS 3.2 need `-webkit-` prefix as well)

Comment: Hi Idan, you should try this..

`border-top-left-radius: 10px;
border-top-right-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;`

Comment: @KheemaPandey Seriously? What's the point?

Comment: yes, it works 15px, you can right and I will accept! THANKS - do you know why it is like that on older versions, any link?

Comment: such a wierd behavior from webkit browser

Comment: @Hashem what you say won't it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to you posted code, it seems you've missed the vendor-prefixes for `box-shadow` property.

[Android 2.1-3.2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) (and iOS 3.2-4.3) needs the `-webkit-` prefix to get the `box-shadow` to work:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
```

Also, in order to create a circle by using `border-radius`, you need to set the radius of the circle as the half of the box dimension (width or height).

Hence, you should use the following:

```
border-radius: 15px;
```

For [Android 2.1 and iOS 3.2](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) the `-webkit-` prefix is needed.

#### Getting all together

```
.switchery > small {
  background: #fff;

  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);

  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;

  -webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* 30px / 2 */
  border-radius: 15px;         /* 30px / 2 */

  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: @IdanShechter Don't mention it :)