# Is it better to specify border-radius in percentages for circle borders?

Tags: css

In general, is it more efficient to use percentages or pixel/em values for border-radii?

For an example: for a square image 200px by 200px, which out of `border-radius:50%` or `border-radius:100px` is best?  Obviously percentages for circles are easier to manage, but are percentages significantly harder to calculate?  Are there any caveats?

This question is assuming the use of a compatible browser, and static-sized images.

Comment: I'd go with `50%` because it is guaranteed to work regardless of the element's dimensions.

Comment: I faced a situation a month ago that the OP couldn't get the percentage values to work on Android 2.3: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21954123/border-radius-and-box-shadow-have-no-effect-in-android-2-3-6

Comment: Depends. Is it always going to be 200px x 200px? If you expect dynamic sizing on the image, and you always want it to be circular, you'd better make sure the border-radius is also dynamic. If the width and height are hardcoded, might as well hardcode border-radius too.

Comment: I've updated my question to be more clear.  Compatibility and dynamic sizing aren't of concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to user percentage values because if I change size of my image, I don't need change my border-radius. But in MDN site you can read this bugs about percentage value:

**percentage values**

- are not supported in older Chrome and Safari versions (it was fixed in Sepember 2010)
- are buggy in Opera prior to 11.50
- are implemented in a non-standard way prior to Gecko 2.0 (Firefox 4). Both horizontal and vertical radii were relative to the width of the border box.
- are not supported in older versions of iOS (prior to 5) and Android versions (prior to WebKit 532)

Check this link for more info: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#_values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#%3Cpercentage%3E_values)

Comment: I've updated my question, if you'd like to change your answer.

Comment: For creating Circle I prefer to use percentage but for any other things I use Pixel because calculate is easy to use